# Convert HEX string that contains ASCII characters

Tags: python, udp, hex, ascii, scapy

I'm having trouble with decoding data (or maybe encoding on send) from scapy.

I'm attempting to send some UDP HEX data with scapy then decode it back to the original form, but the HEX string received has ASCII characters in it.

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, UDP

test_data = ["000ad74340b81e4941002900020202000200"]  # This is actually read from a file.
source_ip = "192.168.1.12"
destination_ip = "192.168.1.4"
source_mac = "70:85:c2:f3:18:8e"
destination_mac = "80:ce:62:f2:94:22"
source_port = 5005
destination_port = 5005
tmp = []

byte_str = [(test_data[0][i:i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(test_data[0]), 2)]

for i in range(len(byte_str)):
    tmp.append(int(f"0x{byte_str[i]}", 16))

data_to_send = bytearray(tmp)
print("b'" + ''.join(f'\\x{c:02x}' for c in data_to_send) + "'")

pkt = Ether(dst=destination_mac, src=source_mac)/\
      IP(dst=destination_ip, src=source_ip, flags=2)/\
      UDP(dport=destination_port, sport=source_port)/data_to_send

del pkt[IP].chksum
del pkt[UDP].chksum

pkt.show2()
sendp(pkt)
```

**Whats being sent**

```
###[ Ethernet ]### 
  dst       = 80:ce:62:f2:94:22
  src       = 70:85:c2:f3:18:8e
  type      = IPv4
###[ IP ]### 
     version   = 4
     ihl       = 5
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = 46
     id        = 1
     flags     = DF
     frag      = 0
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = udp
     chksum    = 0xb75d
     src       = 192.168.1.12
     dst       = 192.168.1.4
     \options   \
###[ UDP ]### 
        sport     = 5005
        dport     = 5005
        len       = 26
        chksum    = 0xaeed
###[ Raw ]### 
           load      = '\x00\n\\xd7C@\\xb8\x1eIA\x00)\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x02\x00'

.
Sent 1 packets.
```

Whats received is `\x00\n\\xd7C@\\xb8\x1eIA\x00)\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x02\x00`, and i'm trying to figure out how i get back to `000ad74340b81e4941002900020202000200` or something like this `\x00\x0a\xd7\x43\x40\xb8\x1e\x49\x41\x00\x29\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x02\x00`.

When i convert `000ad74340b81e4941002900020202000200` to a list of hex values `['00', '0a', 'd7', '43', '40', 'b8', '1e', '49', '41', '00', '29', '00', '02', '02', '02', '00', '02', '00']`, then convert them to a list ints `[0, 10, 215, 67, 64, 184, 30, 73, 65, 0, 41, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0]` to create a bytearray `bytearray(b'\x00\n\xd7C@\xb8\x1eIA\x00)\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x02\x00')`, i can then convert that back to `b'\x00\x0a\xd7\x43\x40\xb8\x1e\x49\x41\x00\x29\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x02\x00'`.

But when i read the payload info from the scapy UDP packet i get the following string `"b'\\x00\\n\\xd7C@\\xb8\\x1eIA\\x00)\\x00\\x02\\x02\\x02\\x00\\x02\\x00'"`, which when i convert it to a bytestring, it still has the `\\` and i can't convert ot back to the original hex data above.

How can i convert str `"\\x00\\n\\xd7C@\\xb8\\x1eIA\\x00)\\x00\\x02\\x02\\x02\\x00\\x02\\x00"` to `b'\x00\n\xd7C@\xb8\x1eIA\x00)\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x02\x00'` with a single `\` so i can then use `print("b'" + ''.join(f'\\x{c:02x}' for c in bytearray(RECEIVED_DATA) + "'")` to get the original hex data back?

Comment: You are aware that `\n` and `0x0a` are the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bytes.hex()` and `str.fromhex()` to convert between representations:

```py
>>> s = "000ad74340b81e4941002900020202000200"  # ASCII string of hex digits
>>> s
'000ad74340b81e4941002900020202000200'
>>> b = bytes.fromhex(s)
>>> b  # Default *display* representation of bytes.
b'\x00\n\xd7C@\xb8\x1eIA\x00)\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x02\x00'
>>> list(b)  # decimal values of the bytes are correct
[0, 10, 215, 67, 64, 184, 30, 73, 65, 0, 41, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0]
>>> # Display a custom way (no ASCII).  This is *just* for display.
>>> print("b'" + ''.join(f'\\x{n:02x}' for n in b) + "'")
b'\x00\x0a\xd7\x43\x40\xb8\x1e\x49\x41\x00\x29\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x02\x00'
>>> b.hex()  # display bytes as hexadecimal string again
'000ad74340b81e4941002900020202000200'
>>> b.hex(sep=' ')  # with a separator if desired.
'00 0a d7 43 40 b8 1e 49 41 00 29 00 02 02 02 00 02 00'
```

Note that the type of a `bytes` object element is `int` so you can iterate over them and perform calculations if needed:

```py
>>> type(b[0])
<class 'int'>
>>> for n in b:
...  print(f'{n:3d} {n:02X}')
...
  0 00
 10 0A
215 D7
 67 43
 64 40
184 B8
 30 1E
 73 49
 65 41
  0 00
 41 29
  0 00
  2 02
  2 02
  2 02
  0 00
  2 02
  0 00
```

Comment: Figured out what my issue was. I was converting the payload data from the packet to a string and didn't realize it with ```payload = str(packet[UDP].payload.load)```. This was adding in the extra ```\``` in the data creating a ```\\``` which was screwing everything up. With the answer above and changing the line to ```payload = packet[UDP].payload.load```, all is good now. Thanks.

Comment: @B3st0fth3w0rst yes using `str` would give you the string display representation of the bytes object. As you found you just want to keep the bytes object.